# How to make <div> grow with content?

Tags: css

I got somethinglike this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<ul>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">


</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</div><!-- end of wrapper -->
</body>
```

and I applied this CSS:

```
#wrapper {
margin:0px auto;
width:100%;
}

#header {
background:#b82626;
}

#content {
clear:both;
float:left;
width:75%;
}

#sidebar {
margin-left:75%;
}

#footer {
clear:both;
height:50px;
}
```

NOW, I need content of header to grow, eg. I add many pages `<li></li>`, and when I exceed the space, the height of header won't grow, just the text overflows the header border and goes into main content.

So, if anyone can suggest me nice rule to apply here, It would be really nice.
I need header  to grow with content.

Thanks

Comment: Your [header grows just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/5TKRU/) with content, I suggest you stop doing whatever it is that's stopping it.

Comment: are you sure you're showing your whole css? growing with content size is the standard behaviour of <div> elements

Comment: Exactly. You say you have "something like this", so why don't you show that instead of this?

Comment: that's all stuff worth mentioning, other styles are just details

Comment: In that case, I'll have to downvote your question. Sorry.

Comment: @MrLister I don't understand you, but never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you floating your list items? If so then you will need to apply a clearfix to the header div.

```
#header:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Even if the OP were floating the list items (or anything in the `#header`), the `#content` already has a `clear:both`, so this isn't necessary.

Comment: YES exactly, I'm floating list elements, works great with this rule, outstanding :D, thanks, best answer ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. In future though you should post your complete code. What you posted in the question was clearly lacking an important detail!